# A regular graph $G$ on $10$ nodes contains $K_6$ as a sub graph. Then the smallest degree of a node in $G$ is:

Tags: graph-theory

A regular graph $G$ on $10$ nodes contains $K_6$ as a sub graph. Then the smallest degree of a node in $G$ is:

So just by drawing a $K_6$ sub graph where I have a $6$ nodes each with degree $5$ and then $4$ extra nodes as my starting point. From there I can increase the degree of the extra nodes to try and get to at least $5$ (since this a regular graph), at which point one of the nodes which make up the $K_6$ sub graph has it's degree increase thereby, we need at least degree $6$ in all the nodes. Repeating this process similarly, I can (maybe this process is time consuming and tends to become quite messy with each iteration) reach the answer which is $9$.

What is the better way to approach this problem and come to a similar conclusion. This question was part of a multiple choice question with the following answers: $9$, $1$, $6$, $5$, and no correct answer provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of updating the degrees of the nodes outside the $K_6$ with each iteration, we can "skip ahead" by reasoning symbolically. Suppose the graph is regular with degree $r$. Then each of the $4$ nodes outside the $K_6$ must have $r$ edges coming out of it; even if $3$ of them go to the other nodes outside the $K_6$, that's $r-3$ edges going to vertices in the $K_6$, for a total of $4(r-3)$ edges from outside the $K_6$ into the $K_6$.

There must exist a vertex of the $K_6$ that receives at least $\frac16$ of the incoming edges: $\frac16 \cdot 4(r-3) = \frac23r - 2$ of them. In addition, it also has $5$ edges to the other vertices of the $K_6$, so it has degree at least $(\frac23r-2)+5 = \frac23r + 3$. But it has degree $r$, so we get $$r \ge \frac23r + 3 \implies \frac13r \ge 3 \implies r \ge 9.$$